# React Router 4 type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have updated to the latest version of react/react-router/...
I am now trying to fix the various issues introduced by all the changes to those dependencies.

Note: my code was working before, it is not anymore because of the newer versions.

So I had this to handle my routes before:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {syncHistoryWithStore, push} from 'react-router-redux';

import configureStore from './store/store';

import App from './components/App';
import EULA from './containers/EULA';
import Main from './containers/Main';
import Blog from './containers/Blog';

const store = configureStore();
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Main} />
                <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
                <Route path="/Feed" component={Blog} />
                <Route path="/Blog" component={Blog} />
                <Route path="/EULA" component={EULA} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

After working on it to fix the history I ended up with what follows. But when I load the site, the content of the navigation bar (declared in App) is shown, but the sub-content of App (ex: Main, or Blog) is not rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import {syncHistoryWithStore, push} from 'react-router-redux';

import configureStore from './store/store';

import App from './components/App';
import Main from './containers/Main';
import Blog from './containers/Blog';
import EULA from './containers/EULA';

const store = configureStore();
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider
    store={store}>
    <Router
      history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/Feed" component={Blog} />
        <Route path="/Blog" component={Blog} />
        <Route path="/EULA" component={EULA} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

After further investigations I found [this site](https://css-tricks.com/react-router-4/) that describe how to migrate to Router 4.
So I tried it and cannot make the example work.
This is what I have now:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router';

const PrimaryHeader = props => {
  return (
    <header>
      Our React Router 4 App
    </header>
  )
}

const HomePage =() => <div>Home Page</div>
const UsersPage = () => <div>Users Page</div>
const UserAddPage = () => <div>Users Add Page</div>

const PrimaryLayout = props => {
  return (
    <div className="primary-layout">
      <PrimaryHeader />
      <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/users/add" component={UserAddPage} />
            <Route path="/users" component={UsersPage} />
            <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <PrimaryLayout />
  </BrowserRouter>
)
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

When I compile and get onto the site I see the following in the console:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
in App

Check the render method of `App`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:42)
    at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:5753)
    at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:7531)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7635)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7756)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:8075)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8221)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
```

---

I have done some further test (using my version that I fixed).
In App render function I was getting the children and rendering them.
Now it seems that children is undefined.
I would venture a guess that it has to do with the fact that in the older version the other routes were children of the "/" {App} route. And that before of the way Router 4 is now it is not the case anymore.
I will have to move children inside main I guess?

But that still does not explain why the simpler example is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is something off in your imports. If you delete your node_modules are rerun `yarn install` (or `npm install`) the compilation should alert you already.

The following code works fine (and as expected for me)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from 'react-router';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const PrimaryHeader = props => {
    return (
        <header>
            Our React Router 4 App
        </header>
    )
};

const HomePage = () => <div>Home Page</div>;
const UsersPage = () => <div>Users Page</div>;
const UserAddPage = () => <div>Users Add Page</div>;

const PrimaryLayout = props => {
    return (
        <div className="primary-layout">
            <PrimaryHeader/>
            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route path="/users/add" component={UserAddPage}/>
                    <Route path="/users" component={UsersPage}/>
                    <Redirect to="/"/>
                </Switch>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
};

const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <PrimaryLayout/>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Changes were:

- Import BrowserRouter from `react-router-dom`
- Add missing imports

This was done with react-router 4.2 and react-router-dom 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks. I thought BrowserRouter could be used from react-router when it actually comes from the react-router-dom. Now I should be abe to rebuild my routes properly.